# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-1_45.lib'

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am getting this error when i tried to build/compile the code is VS2008 C++. the weird thing is i installed boost 1.46.1 but i get this error for boost 1.45.

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-1_45.lib'
i tried looking on different sources. But unfortunately unable to solve it yet. although i included all the paths for libraries and include files.

Please any guidence in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Muhammad

Comment: Maybe you are using the include files of the former version, causing the auto-link mechanism to search for 1.45 libraries as well?

Comment: the thing, i bought this new machine and it has no previous version installed. so i just installed 1.46.1. still confused!

Comment: You should check how boost is linked in your project. Normally it should include only corresponding header files and all the necessary libs are included by the `#pragma comment`.

Answer (score 2):

I've also spent quite some time looking for the solution for this. In my case it was a simple preprocessor definition `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`, which implies you don't need the lib.

If that's not your case, you should probably use `bjam`.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with what you have installed (or not). What is happening is that VC++ expects this library but cannot find it. Check your "included libraries" in your project settings. Perhaps this project is `supposed` to use the 1.45 version.