# Windows 8 RT Linker Error

Tags: linker, windows-runtime, arm, directx

I am trying to compile this [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct3D-HLSL-fractal-e3fb86d9) from for ARM/Windows RT, and I keep getting the following error from my compiler:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'vccorlibd.lib'
```

I did a search on my computer and found this lib does exist and it lives in 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib". So I am not sure what is going wrong. Anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the application contains spaces. Put the path to the lib in double quotes, as per [Why does fatal error "LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'" occur when I compile a C++ project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-c).

If that fails, ensure the directory you mention is in the list of lib search directories. See [LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-1_45.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548883/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-system-vc90-mt-1-45-lib) for more information.

Comment: So in VS 11  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib" is not included by default in all VS projects?

Comment: @Samurai336 Check by going to "Tools" menu -> Options menu item and in the resulting dialog "Projects and Solutions" -> "VC++ Directories" (although this has moved to a property sheet on in VS2012. If the directory is included and not unquoted, check whether something else has the file open already or try compiling in release mode, (since vccorlibd.lib is the debug version).

Comment: So it turns out when I uninstalled VS ultimate it Nerfed my express ARM libs too